# move Gentoo Linux server with Subversion to new location

Tags: linux, svn

I'm moving a Gentoo Linux server with Subversion SVN running on it this weekend to a new physical location, with a new IP address.

My question is:

Do I need to do anything other than change the IP address info (ip/mask/gateway/DNS hosts) and update DNS records for the server?

Is there anything involved with making sure Subversion works properly after the changes?

Comment: Eww. Gentoo. Why?

Comment: How's SVN being served - `svnserve`, ssh, or WebDAV?

Comment: Tom...don't know...it was inherited and nobody wants to mess with it.  It's running Gentoo 1.x from 10 years ago.

Comment: svnserver is a service (sudo netstat -tlnp), WebDAV - is exposed trough apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When moving a server in a different subnet, you need:

- change the IP address and netmask
- change the gateway
- change the DNS /etc/resolver.conf (optional, may be it is the same)
- change DNS A, MX and PTR records for the new IP
- change the SSL certificates if they are issued for a different name (e.g. if you expose SVN via WebDAV)
- update the static routes (probably not needed in your case)
- update mailer if it is not the same and if you use one
- update the backup client/scripts with the new IP

You can test the new IP by adding it as an alias or secondary IP to the ethernet interface.

Comment: Same name...so I guess how SVN is being served doesn't matter, correct?  No need to mess with SSL certs?

Comment: SVN will work fine if you change the IP.